# React and msal with Windows Server AD

Tags: reactjs, .net, authentication, azure-ad-msal, adal

Is it possible to use msal (or adal?) with React and Windows Server Active Directory (on prem - not azure)?

If not the way to authenticate would be a custom login form and JWT token exchange correct? But is this safe? Isnt it a security breach to send the credentials of the custom loginform directly to the api?

Answer (score 2):

You can [implement MSAL in Reactjs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/react). Windows server AD supports custom authentication. This [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/ad-fs-build-custom-auth-method) provides you instructions for implementing a custom authentication method in Window server 2012.

Your control flow for the solution should follow the Credential provider:

First check whether the user is connected to the network. If yes, then communicate with AD server, which is predefined & validates user against AD entry. If user is validated then ask for 2nd factor auth in credential provider only & then on successful validation, pass user to sub-auth module & bypass 2nd factor in sub-auth. If user is not connected to network, then validate with sub-auth module.

If you want the JWT token exchange it is also possible as Window server supports Custom authentication.